# Managing multiple accounts from Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I've two work email accounts from different companies, running on separate domains on Google Apps for Business so they are using Gmail infrastructure. At the moment I'm managing them using Mac Mail which is OK, but I'd like to move to use Gmail in the browser to view / manage / compose emails.

In Mac Mail I can switch between my two accounts like this:

[image: Mac Mail side bar]

Is there something similar inside of Gmail that I can set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is this:

- I set up the ability to send from many e-mail accounts.
- I forward the other accounts to my gmail account.
- I set up label filters for those accounts.
- I select the label to view mail from other accounts.

Answer (score 3):

Google support multiple sign in within same browser. With one account logged in, just try login to another account and google will detect this and guide you.

Comment: Thanks - but this whilst this covers multiple sign ins it dosnt really give me one dashboard to look at my mail is there somthing more allong those lines ?

Answer (score 0):

When you're logged in to Gmail, click on your email address or your image (which could be the default blue head and shoulders) at the top right of the window. A smaller window will open. Click "Add Account" and login to the other account.